# Why does this Typescript generic type inference fail?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have 2 versions of a data model (call them `A` and `B`) and I want to be able to execute functions on instances of these regardless of if they are A or B. The functions themselves are specific to the types A and B.

I have come up with ways to get around this issue, but they all involve declaring a generic type (i.e., `Functions<T>`), which I can't easily do with my current setup.

```js
type A = {
  a: string;
}

type B = {
  b: string;
}

type AFunctions = {
  make: () => A;
  do: (obj: A) => void;
}

type BFunctions = {
  make: () => B;
  do: (obj: B) => void;
}

type Bundle<
  Fns extends AFunctions | BFunctions,
  T extends ReturnType<Fns['make']> = ReturnType<Fns['make']>
> = {
  obj: T,
  fns: Fns,
}

function doIt<M extends AFunctions | BFunctions>(bundle: Bundle<M>) {
  bundle.fns.do(bundle.obj);
}
```

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNwoC+KKokUAQgsmlAEY77HlW31w0GADEAriQDGwIgHsSuVqnQBbDAGsIOABQBKBAD5YVdABNZO2RwBWOGPvhGAbrKKn+dBtCbipM+YqIylBqmjoORkwmUOaWNjhMEVAubh6CjEwSpgA2EAA87CIKUBAAHsAQJKaKohLScsUAPsy+9QEANOwAKiXlldVQAEoQwGIEJF1CeUW4ANoA5KEQ8wC6RojDo+OTkNMKC0urBijrbOhWtlBdnegAZgo4M50Ct3X+JDGyAJLAeQCyvQqVRqrXeimaPjeDVwBm0HCyuQSCPyfwM+mC8KquQAdPdcNjzHDkdiLroPEA)

On the line `bundle.fns.do(bundle.obj);`, I get a typescript error: `Argument of type 'ReturnType<M["make"]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A & B'`

I would expect for `doIt` to be typesafe because `bundle.obj` is the same type as the parameter on `bundle.fns.do`. What's going wrong, here? Is there a way to address this issue without introducing a generic `Functions<T>`?

---

I can also solve it by adding `{ type: 'a' }` and `{ type: 'b' }` parameters to respective `Bundle`s, and then checking:

```js
if (bundle.type === 'a') {
  bundle.fns.do(bundle.obj);
} else if (bundle.type === 'b') {
  bundle.fns.do(bundle.obj);
}
```

but that redundancy is not ideal.

I think it's related to this problem with narrowing generic types: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the compiler is right to complain. Consider the following:

```js
let
func : AFunctions | BFunctions = {
  'make' : function() : A { return {'a': "A"} },
  'do' : function(_ : A) { }
},
someB : B = { 'b' : "B" },
bundle : Bundle<AFunctions | BFunctions> = {
  'obj' : someB,
  'fns' : func,
}
```

This typechecks, but `'do'` is clearly not callable with argument `'obj'`. The fundamental problem is that in `bundle` the type `T` is inferred to be `A | B`, not `A` or `B` based on the type of `make`, as I think you're expecting.

It's not really clear what you want to achieve. In particular, it's not clear why you can't declare a generic type, since this seems to be exactly what you need:

```js
type GenericBundle<X> = { obj : X, do : (obj : X) => void };
type AFunctions = GenericBundle<A>;
type BFunctions = GenericBundle<B>;
type Bundle = AFunctions | BFunctions;

function doIt<X>(bundle: GenericBundle<X>) {
  bundle.do(bundle.obj);
}

let
someA : A = { 'a' : "A" },
someB : B = { 'b' : "B" },
bundle1 : Bundle = {
  'obj' : someA,
  'do' : function(_ : A) { },
},
bundle2 : Bundle = {
  'obj' : someB,
  'do' : function(_ : B) { },
},
bundle3_wrong : Bundle = { // doesn't typecheck
  'obj' : someA,
  'do' : function(_ : B) { },
},
bundle4_wrong : Bundle = { // doesn't typecheck
  'obj' : someB,
  'do' : function(_ : A) { },
};

doIt(bundle1);
doIt(bundle2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will satisfy your use case, but maybe it will help - [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkjB2wICcBmBDAxhAPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgooBbdAawgC4oAKAShKLwG4qoAJgHsWrIQCMAVizxQAPlHTwQnYkQBuQgJYC+AXwoUtiFBmxQAglAgAPJPAEBnWAiRosuC0UrV0AfhZHYGRjAHM+ajpGUVUiCwjBETYJaUtYqE0dfUNjNzNoACFrOwgHZzgTd2wcAu9+cQCoIJD4cP4o5jZ0goThURSWAvTM3QoDClBIKAKAVwcAG1x+ADF4Z1t7JxdK-JwrBVqAGn5ZDdKtgCUIYBnkeDxwXFXHAG0Acg63gF0iUiubu4PSA4Z7vT4-Ci-cj8AZQPDHaioNYsZ7HcaoOaYYBaITwRIwYA4ACyxU25Vcpg8xIIBFY4jmAkWgwZi2pnB8UHpCwgADokY4ecI6SzeSl2NkgA)

The drawback here being the 'any' on the do::obj param (can be 'T | any' or just 'any'), which may or may not matter to you.

Comment: Hey Alex, glad to have you join the community. While posting a link to an example is great, it's better to actually post your code in your answer. Right now, the context is missing. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yeah, I need to avoid `any` - because in this case, if we add `any`, we can call `bundle.fns.do(x)` for any type of `x` without typescript complaining.